# How can I reset transform event with jQuery associated with a button click & HTML5 video end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, mp4

I am having very specific animation that I can't reproduce the way I want it.

I need to simulate transform rotate animation on button click and right after that reset it when html5 video is over so it can rotate back.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.card').css('background', '#646f80');
  $('.cardFront').css('opacity', '1');

  function reset() {
    $('.card').addClass('notransition');
    $('.cardBack').addClass('notransition');
    $('.cardFront').addClass('notransition');
  }

  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $('.cardFront').css('transition', 'visibility 2s, opacity 2s linear');
    $('.cardFront').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.cardFront').css('display', 'none');
    $('.card').css('transform', 'rotateY(180deg)');
    $('.card').css('background', '#fff');
    $('.cardBack').css('display', 'block');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.cardBack').css('opacity', '1');
      $('.cardBack').css('transform', 'rotateY(180deg)');
      $('.cardBack').css('transition', 'visibility 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear');
    }, 350);
    $('.card').css('transform','none');
     $('.cardBack').css('transform','none');
     $('.cardFront').css('transform','none');
  });

  document.querySelector('#backvideo').addEventListener('ended',function(){
    $('.card').addClass('notransition');
    $('.cardBack').addClass('notransition');
    $('.cardFront').addClass('notransition');
    var video = document.getElementById('backvideo');
    video.pause();
    video.currentTime = 0;
    video.load();
    $('.cardBack').css('transition', 'visibility 2s, opacity 2s linear');
    $('.cardBack').css('transform', 'rotateY(180deg)');
    $('.cardBack').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.cardBack').css('display', 'none');
    $('.card').css('transform', 'rotateY(180deg)');
    $('.cardFront').css('transform', 'rotateY(180deg)');
    $('.card').css('background', '#646f80');
    $('.cardFront').css('display', 'block');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.cardFront').css('opacity', '1');
      $('.cardFront').css('transform', 'rotateY(180deg)');
      $('.cardFront').css('transition', 'visibility 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear');
    }, 350);
    reset();
  }, false);

  var lastScrollTop = 0;

  $(window).scroll(function(event){
     var st = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    //
     } else {
       var video = document.getElementById('backvideo');
       video.pause();
       video.currentTime = 0;
       video.load();
       $('.cardBack').css('transition', 'visibility 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear');
       $('.cardBack').css('opacity', '0');
       $('.cardBack').css('display', 'none');
       $('.card').css('transform', 'rotateY(180deg)');
       $('.card').css('background', '#646f80');
       $('.cardFront').css('display', 'block');

       $('.cardFront').css('opacity', '1');
       $('.cardFront').css('transform', 'rotateY(180deg)');
       $('.cardFront').css('transition', 'visibility 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear');
     }
     lastScrollTop = st;
     $('.card').css('transform','none');
     $('.cardBack').css('transform','none');
     $('.cardFront').css('transform','none');
  });

});
```

What I want is very simple :

Click of button flips the .cart box and changes my video & background of the .cart container. After the video is over I want to again flip to the first video version.

Here is some of the html to get a more relevant reference :

```
              <div class="card">
                <div class="cardFront"><video id="frontvideo" src="img/gifs/seq_dark.mp4" preload="auto" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline=""></video></div>
                <div class="cardBack"><video id="backvideo" src="img/gifs/seq_light.mp4" preload="auto" autoplay="" muted="" playsinline=""></video></div>
              </div>
```

I hope someone can help me with that!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my problem with converting from inline css, to class. This prevents from using !important ability, and it resets all classes perfectly as I wanted.
Here is the fixed code, if anyone needs similar solution. The css you can see in my question above.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.card').addClass('greybg');
  $('.cardFront').addClass('visible');

  $('.btn_amz').click(function() {
    $('.btn_amz').addClass('stop');
    $('.card').removeClass('greybg');
    $('.cardFront').removeClass('visible');
    $('.cardFront').removeClass('showfront');
    $('.cardFront').addClass('hidefront');
    $('.cardFront').addClass('flipcard');
    $('.card').addClass('flipcard');
    $('.card').removeClass('rotatetoblack');
    $('.card').addClass('rotatetowhite');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.cardBack').removeClass('hideback');
      $('.cardBack').addClass('showback');
    }, 350);

  });

  document.querySelector('#backvideo').addEventListener('ended',function(){

    var video = document.getElementById('backvideo');
    video.pause();
    video.currentTime = 0;
    video.load();
    $('.btn_amz').removeClass('stop');
    $('.cardBack').addClass('flipcard');
    $('.card').addClass('flipcard');
    $('.cardBack').removeClass('showback');
    $('.cardBack').addClass('hideback');
    $('.card').removeClass('rotatetowhite');
    $('.card').addClass('rotatetoblack');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.cardFront').removeClass('hidefront');
      $('.cardFront').addClass('showfront');
    }, 350);
    $('.cardBack').removeClass('flipcard');
    $('.card').removeClass('flipcard');
  }, false);

  var lastScrollTop = 0;

  $(window).scroll(function(event){
     var st = $(this).scrollTop();
     if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    //
     } else {
       var video = document.getElementById('backvideo');
       video.pause();
       video.currentTime = 0;
       video.load();
       $('.btn_amz').removeClass('stop');
       $('.cardBack').addClass('flipcard');
       $('.card').addClass('flipcard');
       $('.cardBack').removeClass('showback');
       $('.cardBack').addClass('hideback');
       $('.card').removeClass('rotatetowhite');
       $('.card').addClass('rotatetoblack');
       setTimeout(function() {
         $('.cardFront').removeClass('hidefront');
         $('.cardFront').addClass('showfront');
       }, 350);
       $('.cardBack').removeClass('flipcard');
       $('.card').removeClass('flipcard');
     }
     lastScrollTop = st;
  });
```